# Does anyone know the how to make the webview transparent so that it will show the video preview on Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

```
// Start a scan. Scanning will continue until something is detected or
// `QRScanner.cancelScan()` is called.
QRScanner.scan(displayContents);

function displayContents(err, text){
  if(err){
   // an error occurred, or the scan was canceled (error code `6`)
 } else {
   // The scan completed, display the contents of the QR code:
   alert(text);
 }
}

// Make the webview transparent so the video preview is visible behind it.
QRScanner.show();
// Be sure to make any opaque HTML elements transparent here to avoid
// covering the video.
```

Over here, I have to make the webview transparent so that the video preview is visible, but as I am very new to Ionic, I am unsure of what it is asking me to do and under which file directory that webview file is at, I hope that you guys are willing to help me out with this one and any form of help is deeply appreciated

This is the link for the pluggin
https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution, I just had to add these in the page's .scss page

```
html, body, ion-app, ion-content, ion-page, .nav-decor{
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute available in ionic called `transparent`. It will do the same thing as what you have done.
Usage:

Use it in a header to make it transparent.

```
<ion-header transparent></ion-header>
```

Comment: This solution does not work though, I have tried it already, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

Cordova adds a `<video>` tag. So you will have to get view tag and increase its `z-index`

Like below:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].setAttribute('z-index', '100');
```

Make sure you hide all elements above this video tag like popup or any other html element.